How to get last digit of an integer ended with (0 or 5)
Looking for algorithm
Integer Properties

Integer is ended with 0 or 5

Example: 64454542420, 83186482697426868635

Integer is very big.

Aim:

Want to get last digit of the integer. So result is 0 or 5

Output and execution time is to be same as
in MOD 10



Limitation

I can not use /, %, string operators or any other operator

Only +, -, *, >, <, =  can be used


I can do it by iteration and repeatedly adding -10
int = int - 10 

........

........

repeat and finally get the followings:


if int = 0; then end is 0

if int = 5; then end is 0

Problem

Extremely large time is required for big integer.

Bounty

Your time and thinking is valuable to me as it is complex finding. So, I will give $300 to the first person who can give perfect solution of it. Payment method - Crypto

Clue
My clue suppose int = 115, now add 5 = 120 now sub 10 = 110 for ending 5. if int = 110 now add 5 = 115, sub 10 = 105 ....... like this way....
Or
Try to eliminate digit from the left making 0. Finally it may possible to get 5 or 0.  Think about adding or subtracting 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000 ete using loop

How to get last digit of an integer is one allowed to do n=83186482697426868635;  Last[IntegerDigits[n]] ? This gives last digit 5

This doesn't seem to be a question about the software Mathematica or Wolfram language. If you're interested in algorithm, perhaps this is a question for https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/

@CrimsonDark Seems that OP is using PHP: https://stackoverflow.com/q/79092180/1551513

It is about mathematic. PHP forum could not solve the algorithm

Algorithm to find last digit of an integer without using / or % or decimal number

Answer. Since your number is 0 or 5 mod 10, then ... if it is even, the last digit is zero, if it is odd, the last number is 5. So you only need to determine NUMBER mod 2. Easy. Find , using simple multiplication, the largest power of 2 not exceeding your number. Subtract repeatedly without going negative. Repeat the process of finding the largest power of 2 not exceeding. Repeat. Eventually you will have either a 1 or a 2 ... or alternatively a 1 or a zero. If zero, your number ends in zero. If 1, then your number ends in 5.

Can not use MOD

I'm not suggesting using mod, at all. Read again. You need to determine whether it is 0 or 1 mod 2 ... but that doesn't require a mod operator. The solution I have given uses only the operators you asked for.

Why will I evaluate 0 or 1 mod 2 ?  no way to use mod

Unfortunately you are being lazy. READ THE ANSWER. I can implement this in less than 25 lines of code. And nowhere is there a MOD operator.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I don't know if MMA allows for it easily, but if you can just read the last bit of an integer you're basically done.

@SjoerdSmit I don't think it's quite that easy... there are methods for summing up differences of odd and even bit sequence differences and seeing if they are divisible by five, which obvious converge, but such bit ops aren't natively very efficient in Mma...

Try this one:
x = 83186482697426868635;

red[a_] := Module[{p = 1, q = 10, r},
  Catch[
   Do[If[a - q < 0,
     Do[If[a - q + r >= 0, Throw[a - q + r]], {r, p, q, p}],
     p = q; q = 10*q], Infinity]]
  ]
NestWhile[red[#] &, x, # > 10 &]

or
NestWhile[(p = 1; q = 10; 
       Catch[Do[
         If[# - q < 0, 
          Do[If[# - q + r >= 0, Throw[# - q + r]], {r, p, q, p}], 
           p = q; q = 10*q], Infinity]]) &, x, # > 10 &]


slow for big integer

@AsifIqbal How slow? On my laptop Timing[NestWhile[red[#] &, x, # > 10 &]] for a 1000-digit integer yields 0.38 seconds. What is your performance goal?

Also I am not willing to use Module

Excellent. Let me check. If it works I will send you usdt. Give me your telegram id.

@AsifIqbal Thank you for accepting! This is already a good award for me.
